# achieving same font size in all android devices

Tags: android, cordova, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a hybrid mobile application using phonegap. I want to display text which should look similar in size on all android/ios devices. it should work in all resolutions.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Conditions are like,

i just want to avoid media queries like

```
@media only screen and  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio : 1){
        .todo-actions{
            font-size: 70%;
    }
}

@media only screen  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio : 1.9){

        .todo-actions{
        font-size: 120%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26537865

Remove **target-densitydpi=device-dpi** from meta tag.